# Which is the impossible voting in election?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Three candidates A, B, C are contesting an election. In an opinion poll fraction $a$ of voters prefer A to B, fraction $b$ prefer B to C and fraction $c$ prefer C to A. then which of the following preferences are impossible for $(a,b,c)$?

1. $(0.51,0.51,0.51)$
2. $(0.61,0.71,0.71)$
3. $(0.68,0.68,0.68)$
4. $(0.49,0.49,0.49)$

Based on the options 1. and 2. are not possible as both reflect same scenario. But i couldn't do this problem in a systematic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are six possible preference orders for the candidates:

- $d$: A>B>C
- $e$: A>C>B
- $f$: B>A>C
- $g$: B>C>A
- $h$: C>A>B
- $i$: C>B>A

From this, $a = d + e + f$, $b = f + g + i$, and $c = e + h + i$.

$a + b +c = d + 2e + 2f + g + h + 2i \le 2(d + e + f + g + h + i) = 2(\text{# of voters})$.

In scenario (3), $a + b + c = 204\%$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** there are six classes of preferences:

1. Those who prefer A (to both B and C) and prefer B to C.
2. Those who prefer A (to both B and C) and prefer C to B.
3. Those who prefer B (to both A and C) and prefer A to C.
4. Those who prefer B (to both A and C) and prefer C to A.
5. Those who prefer C (to both A and B) and prefer A to B.
6. Those who prefer C (to both A and B) and prefer B to A.

(assuming that each polled individual has made its mind, it might also be cases with no preferences.)

Note that $a$ is the sum of cases 1., 2. and 5., and that cases 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., and 6. add up $1$ (at most).